# How to simplify $\sum_{i=0}^{2n - d - 1} {n \choose i}$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Is it possible and how could I simplify this sum into a formula who's quantity of operations is independent of `n`?

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{2n - d - 1} {n \choose i}
$$

`i`,`n` and `d` are natural numbers and `d >= n`.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{i=0}^{2n - d - 1} {n \choose i}$$ ?

Comment: @DanielV Yes, thanks. I don't know how to write the formula here.

Comment: possible duplicate http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Answer (score 1):

As $d\geq n$, it would be easier to refer to how much bigger $d$ is from $n$, lets call it $\delta = d-n$.

So, $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n-d-1}\binom{n}{i} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-(d-n)-1}\binom{n}{i} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-\delta-1}\binom{n}{i}$

This should look familiar.  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i} = 2^n$, however in our case we stopped a bit early.  In an attempt to make the sum we are working with look more like the complete sum:

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-\delta-1}\binom{n}{i} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-\delta-1}\binom{n}{i} + \sum\limits_{i=n-\delta}^{n}\binom{n}{i} - \sum\limits_{i=n-\delta}^{n}\binom{n}{i} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i} - \sum\limits_{i=n-\delta}^{n}\binom{n}{i} = 2^n - \sum\limits_{i=n-\delta}^{n}\binom{n}{i}$

This can be simplified a little further if you prefer working with smaller indexes than larger due to the property that $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$

$=2^n - \sum\limits_{i=0}^\delta \binom{n}{i}$

Replacing $\delta$ back with $d-n$ if desired will complete the simplifications we can make without knowing what $n$ and $d$ actually are.  Note, the number of iterations in the remaining sum, although potentially fewer, will still rely on the relationship between $n$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading now about the power set identity. This could help but I'm hoping for something with a number of operations independent of n.

Comment: Looks like someone asked this before on math.stackexchange: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes, I noticed when you posted that as a comment above 20 hours ago.  Notice that the give only bounds but not exact amounts except for a few trivial special cases.  It would seem probable that any simplification will remain either inexact or would require knowledge of the relationship between $n$ and $d$, or will require a number of operations dependent on $n$.